# Express-session Authorization

Tags: javascript, session, express, cookies

I'm quite new to express.js, and I'm trying to make a session-cookie after you've logged in. I'm able to start the session, and able to login successfully, but the session doesn't seem to come along to the next directory. I didn't include the bodyparser-thingy before starting the session.

```
router.use(bodyParser.json());

router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

router.use(session({
name:   "authorization",
secret: "secret",
saveUninitialized: false,
resave: false,
cookie: {
    secure: true,
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
},
}));

    router.route("/login")
        .get(function(request, response) {

    response.render("../views/partials/login");
})

.post(function(request, response, next) {

    let username = request.body.username;
    let password = request.body.password;

    User.findOne({user: username}, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            throw err
        }

        // test password if matching
        if (user !== null) {
            user.comparePassword(password, function(err, match) {
                if (err || !match)
                }

                request.session.user = username;     // These seems to not follow
                request.session.password = password;
            });
        } else {
            response.redirect("/login");
        }
    });

});
```

But when I redirect to "/home", the request.session.user returns undefined

```
request.session.user -> undefined

function restrict(req, res, next) {
    if (req.session) {
        next();
    } else {
        req.session.error = "Access denied!";
        res.sendStatus(403);
    }
}
router.route("/home")
.get(restrict, function(request, response) {
    console.log(request.session.user) ---> undefined
```

Why aren't there any user in the cookie?

Sorry if this is a nooby question.

(P.S. I do not want to use any platform like passport etc.)
(P.S.S I know the error-handling isn't the best, but it's temporary)

Comment: Do you use the cookie parser middleware?

Comment: @Mouneer yes I do!

Comment: About your **cookie.secure** flag, from documentation:
`Note be careful when setting this to true, as compliant clients will not send the cookie back to the server in the future if the browser does not have an HTTPS connection.` So do you use https connection?

Comment: That actually made it work, can't believe I missed that in the documentation and that it was that simple. Thanks @Mouneer :)

Comment: Great, check my answer. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your **cookie.secure** flag, from documentation:

> Note be careful
>   when setting this to true, as compliant clients will not send the
>   cookie back to the server in the future if the browser does not have
>   an HTTPS connection.

From your comments, you don't use https connection and the cookie isn't sent to the server.